# SQL Server Date Column + 7 Days less is than Today's Date

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to work out a way to update a column (`LostRenewalCount`) if several / all conditions are met on the same row:

1. RowSubType = 1
2. Submission Status Code = BIN
3. Policy Effective Date + 7 Days is Less than Todays date

Code:

```
update SubmissionActivitySLXStaging
set LostRenewalCount = case
                          when RowSubType = 'Renewal' then '1'
                          when [Submission Status Code] <> 'BIN' then '1'
                          when dateadd (dd, 7, [Policy Effective Date]) < GETDATE()) then '1'
                          else '0'
                       end
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a WHERE clause.... `update SubmissionActivitySLXStaging set LostRenewalCount = [whatever you are updating it to] WHERE RowSubType = 'Renewal' AND [Submission Status Code] = 'BIN' AND Dateadd (dd, 7, [Policy Effective Date]) < GETDATE())`

Comment: J.D. thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think about making one update statement per "condition" or set of conditions, like this:

```
UPDATE SubmissionActivitySLXStaging
   SET LostRenewalCount = 1
 WHERE RowSubType = 'Renewal'
   AND [Submission Status Code] <> 'BIN'
   AND DATEADD(DD, 7, [Policy Effective Date]) < GETDATE()
```

After that you can but update statements together with all the other "sets of conditions"

Reason to split it into multiple statements is that readability goes a long way!